# Stack Overflow error while running a list

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm studying data structures and I have to do a double linked list by myself, creating Node and List objects instead of using the Java implementation LikedList, and I'm having a Stack Overflow error every time I tried to add 2 elements in the list, and I don't know why. Could you please help me?

```
public class DoubleLinked {
    Node head;
    Node tail;
    int size;

    public DoubleLinked() {
        head = tail = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void insertOnHead(int x) {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.value = x;
        if(head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            size++;
        } else {
            newNode.next = head;
            head.previous = newNode;
            head = newNode;
            size++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[Head: " + head + ", Tail: " + tail + ", Size: "
                + size + "]";
    }
}


public class Node {

    int value;
    Node next;
    Node previous;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node [Value: " + value + ", Next: " + next + ", Previous: " + previous + "]";
    }
}
```

It inserts the first element(5) but not the second(6).

Main:

```
public class DEMain 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        DoubleLinked l1 = new DoubleLinked();

        l1.insertOnHead(5);
        l1.insertOnHead(6);
        System.out.println(l1);

    }
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:63) 
at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:109) 
at DoblementeEnlazadas.Nodo.toString(Nodo.java:12) 
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854) 
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128) 
at DoblementeEnlazadas.Nodo.toString(Nodo.java:12)
```

Comment: The first step is to read, and post, the exception stack trace. It tells you, and us, where the problem is.

Comment: Also, provide the code where you make your test. Currently, this code should not give `StackOverflowError` (even if it won't work as expected).

Comment: Please don't put code and stacktraces in comments.  Put them in the question itself and make them legible.

Comment: It is the second time I use this site, sorry, thank you for noticing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception stack trace would confirm it, but the problem is quite obvious:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Node [Value: " + value + ", Next: " + next + ", Previous: " + previous + "]";
}
```

So, when you transform a node to a string, you also transform its both neighbours. That causes their `toString()` method to be called, which transforms their 2 neighbours, which causes their `toString()` method to be called, which transforms their 2 neighbours, etc. etc.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but I used the same to print a LinkedList and it run perfectly, how do I do this then to make it work.

Comment: Hint:  What is this->next->prev?  (Oops! Java, I forgot)  What is this.next.prev?

Comment: If you mean a singly-linked list, then of course it works, since a Node of a singly-linked list only has one neighbor, and doesn't have cyclic references like a doubly-linked list has. Just change your toString() method so that it prints only the next node, and not the previous one.  Or even better, don't make it print the internals of the list (nodes), but only its values: `[1, 24, 54, 32]`.

Comment: I see now, another easy question for you guys, if I try to implement the Circular LinkedList the same way I should print the next node and not the previous like you told me, right?

Comment: No, of course not. Think about what would happen. The list is circular. So if each node prints its next one, you'll have, literally, an infinite loop, which will also cause a stackoverflow error. Just like if you asked children to form a circle and ask each child to say the name of his right neighbor. It would never end, since it's a circle.

Comment: I see, so in that case should I print only the values of each node?, is there a posible way to print the list and not get the loop?